# Custom trustStore with cacerts as a fallback for keys not in custom trustStore

Tags: java, ssl

Is there a way via command line or via a custom Trust Manager, to create a custom trustStore that is backed by the cacerts?

The application uses a custom trustStore:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/SSL/CATrust.jks
```

To hold our own trust certs and this was done in a custom file to simplify the upgrading of a JDK without having to migrate the cacerts.

The problem is that the cacerts carries so many standard certs, which we have not imported into CATrust.jks.  Because of this, we receive SSL errors because the custom CATrust.jks that is supplied via the command-line property is exclusive and not additive (in addition to the cacerts certs).

So is there a way to supply a custom trustStore and if the cert is not found within that trustStore, the server/application will fallback to trying to find the cert within the cacerts (or a secondardy trustStore)?

So far from the initial reading and other posts, the information talks about only having a single trustStore where all CA certs are.

Answer (score 6):

As part of your deployment, you could make a copy of the default `cacerts` and import the contents of your own keystore into it (or the other way around):

```
cp /path/to/cacerts merged.jks
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /SSL/CATrust.jks -destkeystore merged.jks
```

It would certainly be better to avoid using the same alias names (check the options for `keytool -importkeystore` for further details, especially if this has to be part of a script).